# Pyrocms issue : How to display Single record from table in page using tags

Tags: codeigniter, html-table, record, pyrocms

I have created a plugin which brings a record from db table. Now I want to display the record into the page. I am trying to use tags but unable to get it working. How can I do that?
Here is the detail:

Plugin

```
class Plugin_News extends Plugin  
{  
   function getNewsDetails()  
   {  
    $this->load->model('news/news_m');
    $result =   $this->news_m->getNews();

    return $this->attribute('result',$result);
   }       
}
```

Model

```
public function getNews()
{       
    $id =   isset($_REQUEST['id']) ? $_REQUEST['id'] : 0;

    if($id > 0 )
    {
        $where  =   "WHERE id = $id"; 
    }else{
        $where  =   " ";
    }

    $sql_query  ="    SELECT 
                        id,
                        news_title , 
                        news_description ,
                    FROM default_news 
                    $where";
    $query  =   $this->db->query($sql_query);
    return  $query->row();
}
```

And here is how I am trying to call it

```
{{ News:getNews }}  
<li><a href  = "http://localhost/lc/index.php/newsdetail?id={{ id }}">{{ news_title }}</a></li>
{{ /News:getNews }}
```

And in the page newsdetails to display single record

```
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>{{ News:getNewsDetails news_title}}  </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>{{ News:getNewsDetails description }}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Its not working and i cant understand the right syntex and found nothing in the documentation clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well after a little research i have found this alternative.
In the model return this

```
return  $query->result();
```

But the query should be limited to 1

```
SELECT id,news_title , news_description ,FROM default_news $where limit 1
```

And in the page simply create a loop to display stuff

```
{{ News:getNewsDetails}} 
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>{{ title }}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>{{ description }}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
{{ /News:getNewsDetails}}
```

I know this is not perfect but this holds for my requirement.

Comment: That's the correct way!
If you have more truoble see the docs: http://docs.pyrocms.com/2.1/manual/index.php/developers/addons/developing-plugins

Answer (score 0):

just a quicker way in your model

you can use this line in your model

```
public function getNews()
{       
    $id =   isset($_REQUEST['id']) ? $_REQUEST['id'] : 0;
    if($id > 0 )
    {
        $where  =   "id = $id"; 
    }else{
        $where  =   "";
    }
    return $this->db->select('id, news_title , news_description')
           ->from('news')->where($where)->get()->row();
}
```

Comment: well thanks but i have already tried returning a row but in the page i dont know how to use it